# SNR аудио файла

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav

Мне нужно вычислить SNR аудио файла. Нашел информацию, что в есть готовая функция в пакете: scipy.stats.signaltonoise. Но не нашел примеров использования. Как эта функция собственно работает( вычисляет)?

еще нашел такой пример:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import numpy
import os.path
 
def snr(file):
  if (os.path.isfile(file)):
    data = wavfile.read(fileWav)[1]
    singleChannel = data
    try:
      singleChannel = numpy.sum(data, axis=1)
    except:
      # was mono after all
      pass
 
    norm = singleChannel / (max(numpy.amax(singleChannel), -1 * numpy.amin(singleChannel)))
    return stats.signaltonoise(norm)
```

может кто уже писал что то такое?

Comment: `signaltonoise` - была убрана из `scipy.stats` - в современных версиях scipy ее нет. [Здесь уже смотрели?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199124/test-of-signal-to-noise-ratio-snr-db-function-in-python) У вас есть формула по которой считается SNR?

Comment: @MaxU, думаю, стандартную формулу происать. Через отношение амплитуд.

Comment: @MaxU, или не пойдет?

Answer (score 1):

Эта функция была удалена из `SciPy.stats` API, и начиная с версии 0.16 она отсутствует в `SciPy.stats`.

[Вот определение данной функции (из старой версии scipy)](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/0.15.x/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1898-L1925):

```
def signaltonoise(a, axis=0, ddof=0):
    """
    The signal-to-noise ratio of the input data.
    Returns the signal-to-noise ratio of `a`, here defined as the mean
    divided by the standard deviation.
    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        An array_like object containing the sample data.
    axis : int or None, optional
        If axis is equal to None, the array is first ravel'd. If axis is an
        integer, this is the axis over which to operate. Default is 0.
    ddof : int, optional
        Degrees of freedom correction for standard deviation. Default is 0.
    Returns
    -------
    s2n : ndarray
        The mean to standard deviation ratio(s) along `axis`, or 0 where the
        standard deviation is 0.
    """
    a = np.asanyarray(a)
    m = a.mean(axis)
    sd = a.std(axis=axis, ddof=ddof)
return np.where(sd == 0, 0, m/sd)
```

Comment: спасибо. А вы не знаете, есть ли замена этой функции?

Comment: @asai94, вы можете взять эту как есть (из ответа) и попробовать...